# Unity. Joystick Pack. Можно ли сделать snapX джойстика в собственном скрипте?

Tags: unity3d, скрипт

Можно ли сделать snapX джойстика в собственном скрипте?

Comment: вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ